# Creating a smooth randomly generated line

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have been trying to follow this example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523418/given-a-line-of-two-points-constrict-the-drawing-of-the-next-line-within-a-cert/2525305?noredirect=1#comment5214859_2525305) to create a smooth randomly generated line point by point.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
var ptheta = 50;
var theta = 50;
var px = 0;
var py = 0;
var x = 50;
var y = 50;
var a = 0.3;

var rand = 0;
var angleVar = 0;


function animate(){
    rand = Math.random() * (10.0 - 1.0) * 1.0;
    angleVar = ((2*rand-1) * a * Math.PI);
    theta = ptheta + angleVar;
    px = x;
    py = y;
    r = rand//Math.random() * (10.0 - 1.0) * 1.0;
    x = (px + r * Math.cos(ptheta));
    y = (py + r * Math.sin(ptheta));
    ptheta = theta;

    //draw
    ctx.lineWidth = 3 //make this random
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(this.px, this.py)
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.color
    ctx.lineTo(this.x, this.y)
    ctx.lineCap = "round"
    ctx.stroke()
}
```

It looks like the code almost does what's necessary of it. It indeed creates a randomly generated line, but i encounter two problems:

1. The line that is generated is way too small. Any small change I make to the algorithm makes it so that the line is way too huge. I cant quite understand as to why this happens.
2. The line doesn't exactly seem to follow the rules outlined in the link provided. There still seems to be jarring changes in direction, something that the accepted answer in the link provided says this should avoid.

I am trying to achieve this using an html canvas and drawing strokes on it using the code below and the example provided above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: [Here's a link to a codepen example](https://codepen.io/ccioanca/pen/ooEqqQ)

Comment: Can you please add a link to a repro of your problem? Like jsbin or codepen.


When you say that the line is too small, do you mean short or thin?

Comment: added link to a codepen project. the thickness of the line can be edited easily, the length of the lines based on the algorithm i cant wrap my head around though. I'd say the lines are too short. or rather, the maximum length of a line is too short.

Comment: This line:

`rand = Math.random() * (10.0 - 1.0) * 1.0;`

is the same as:

`rand = Math.random() * 9;`

Math.random() returns a value between 0-1 which means that rand will be a value between 0 and 9. If you'd like it to take bigger steps you can multiply with a number that is bigger than 9.

Comment: You're completely right, and that seems to solve that problem. Though the problem im more concerned with is the second one, where it seems that i followed the algorithm to a T and yet, the line still seems to make some sharp turns. If you can figure that out, i'll be very thankful!

Comment: I Forked your Pen and made some modifications: https://codepen.io/DonKarlssonSan/pen/WXMzqp

 * Have one random value for rand which is used to set the new angle, since you thing it takes too sharp turns use `rand = Math.random();` which will give you values between 0-1 instead of 0-9
 * Have a separate random value for r which is used to control the step length, like `r = Math.random() * 20;` 
 * You could also place the starting point in the middle of the screen if you want to by:  `var x = window.innerWidth / 2; var y = window.innerHeight / 2;`

Comment: man you're the best. post this as an answer and ill give it an accept and an upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [created a fork](https://codepen.io/DonKarlssonSan/pen/WXMzqp) of your Pen and made some modifications:

- Have one random value for rand which is used to set the new angle, since you think it takes too sharp turns use `rand = Math.random();` which will give you values between 0-1 instead of 0-9
- Have a separate random value for r which is used to control the step length, like `r = Math.random() * 20;`
- Place the starting point in the middle of the screen if you want to by:

  var x = window.innerWidth / 2; 
  var y = window.innerHeight / 2;